# compile with phonegap cordova on windows 7

Tags: cordova, windows-phone

I have some problem trying to compile my application for Windows Phone.

The error i am getting in the console is this:

```
C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.App
XPackage.Targets(1752,9): error MSB6006: "MakeAppx.exe" salió con el código 1.
[C:\Users\oboz\Desktop\myapp\platforms\windows\CordovaApp.Windows.jsproj]
ERROR: Error code 1 for command: C:\Program Files\MSBuild\12.0\bin\msbuild with
args: C:\Users\oboz\Desktop\myapp\platforms\windows\CordovaApp.Windows.jsproj,/clp
:NoSummary;NoItemAndPropertyList;Verbosity=minimal,/nologo,/p:Configuration=debu
g,/p:Platform=anycpu
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 2

You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 2
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\oboz\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cor
dova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:134:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1087:5)
```

My operating system is Windows 7 32 Bits and I have installed visual studio 2010 and 2013 with the SDK for Windows Phone 8 but anything seems to work. I will appreciate any help you can give me. I am using the latest build of node.js and cordova.